Flutter GetX Translation not working for local_notification action in background
I am working on a Flutter application where I use Firebase Messaging for push notifications and GetX for state management and translations. I have a local notification action that should display translated text. Everything works fine when the app is in the foreground, but when the app is in the background, the translation for the notification action button is not applied. I suspect that the translation files are not being loaded correctly in the background context.
Here's the relevant part of my code according to flutter documentation for notifications:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:macnil_gtfleet_mobile/shared/models/refuel_info.dart';
import 'package:macnil_gtfleet_mobile/shared/widgets/fuel_detection_panel.dart';

void openFuelDetectionWidget(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  final payload = notificationResponse.payload;
  if (payload != null) {
    RefuelInfo activityInfo = RefuelInfo.fromJson(payload);
    Get.put(ActivitiesController());
    Get.bottomSheet(
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FuelDetectionWidget(
          activityInfo: activityInfo,
        ),
      ),
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,
      barrierColor: GtColors.uiPrimary.withOpacity(0.7),
      isScrollControlled: false,
    );
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(
    NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
  final bool shouldOpenFuelDetection =
      notificationResponse.payload?.contains('REFUELING') ?? false;
  if (shouldOpenFuelDetection) {
    openFuelDetectionWidget(notificationResponse);
  }
  debugPrint(
      "Background notification action tapped: ${notificationResponse.actionId}");
}

class LocalNotificationsConfig {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {},
      notificationCategories: [
        DarwinNotificationCategory(
          'actions',
          actions: <DarwinNotificationAction>[
            DarwinNotificationAction.plain('1', 'action1'.tr),
          ],
          options: <DarwinNotificationCategoryOption>{
            DarwinNotificationCategoryOption.hiddenPreviewShowTitle,
          },
        ),
      ],
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
        final bool shouldOpenFuelDetection =
            notificationResponse.payload?.contains('REFUELING') ?? false;
        if (shouldOpenFuelDetection) {
          debugPrint(
              "Foreground notification action tapped: ${notificationResponse.actionId}");
          openFuelDetectionWidget(notificationResponse);
        }
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> createNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'GT Fleet 365',
          'GT Fleet 365',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          color: GtColors.uiPrimary,
          actions: message.data['messageParams']?.contains('REFUELING')
              ? <AndroidNotificationAction>[
                  AndroidNotificationAction(
                    '1',
                    'action1'.tr,
                    showsUserInterface: true,
                    cancelNotification: false,
                    titleColor: GtColors.uiPrimary,
                  ),
                ]
              : null,
        ),
        iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(categoryIdentifier: 'actions'),
      );

      String notificationTitle =
          message.data['title'] ?? message.notification?.title ?? '';
      String notificationBody =
          message.data['body'] ?? message.notification?.body ?? '';

      await notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        notificationTitle,
        notificationBody,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: message.data['messageParams'],
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error showing notification: $e');
    }
  }
}


Why is the translation not applied to the notification action when the app is in the background?
How can I ensure that the translation files are correctly loaded and available in the background context?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
